# Rails 4 scope has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, has-many

I have two models

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_types, dependent: :destroy
end

class ProjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio
end
```

ProjectType model has field `ptype`. It can be 'web' or 'mobile', etc.
How can I get all 'web' or 'mobile' portfolios using scopes?

Comment: Like `scope :web, -> { where(ptype: 'web') }`?

Comment: @Stefan it will return list of projectTypes, not portfolios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an appropriate scope to your model:

```
# in models/project_type.rb
class ProjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio

  scope :web, -> { where(ptype: 'web') }
end
```

To load portfolios with type `web` only use that scope with a join in the controller:

```
# in the controller
@web_portfolios = Portfolio.joins(:project_types).merge(ProjectType.web)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have explicit scopes for both, or you may have one scope that selects for you based on ptype, or you may metaprogram a scope for each unique ptype in the database.  If you are adding a variety of different "ptypes" you can do any of the following which will give you a scope for handling any "ptypes":

```
scope :ptype, -> (ptype) { where(ptype: ptype) }
```

called as:

```
ProjectType.ptype('web')
```

or

```
class ProjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.pluck(:ptype).each do |ptype|
      scope ptype.gsub(/\s+/,"_").downcase.to_sym, -> { where(ptype: ptype) }
   end
end
```

I don't recommend this and I also don't recommend individual scopes for each "string" (e.g. ProjectType.web or ProjectType.mobile) in there.  The best balance is to pass a string value into a scope which retrieves what you are looking for.  Just my opinion, I'm sure others feel differently about it.

To be honest, I think the ptype field is ripe for an enumerator -- this will give some clarity in your code and define what that field actually expects as opposed to allowing any string to be placed in there at random.  So something like:

```
class ProjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum ptype: [:web, :mobile]

   scope :ptype, -> (ptype) { where(ptype: self.ptypes[ptype] }
 end
```

and called like so:

```
ProjectType.ptype(:web)
```

I don't think any one of these solutions presented here or above is any more "right", except the meta-programming solution that's generating a scope for each string in the ptype field stored in the database.

Finally, here is a scope for your Portfolio:

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :by_ptype, -> (ptype) { joins(:project_type).merge(ProjectType.ptype(ptype) }  
 end
```

And called like so:

```
 Portfolio.by_ptype(:web)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following a Rails 4.1 approach I would consider my ptype field an enum and write this:

```
class ProjectType < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :portfolio
   enum ptype: { web: 'web', mobile: 'mobile' }
end
```

This will give you:

```
ProjectType.web
ProjectType.mobile
```

scopes to fetch objects based on ptype, but will give you also other useful methods like:

```
@projectType.web?
@projectType.web!
```

Please refer to docs: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

In here you ask how to retrieve "web" `Portfolio` and I will suppose you mean "All Portfolio with at least a ProjectType of ptype 'Web'.

Then I would write something like:

```
 Portfolio.joins(:project_types).merge(ProjectType.web)
```

see docs: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge

In a final refinement you can then create a scope out of it:

```
class Portfolio
   has_many :project_types
   scope :web, -> { joins(:project_types).merge(ProjectType.web) }
end
```

and call just

```
Portfolio.web
```

Comment: Your enum values should be integers.

Comment: they can but they don't have to. I would suggest to use strings as values in database for readability reasons. This is also much more managable in case you need to add new keys or removing or reorder existing ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
class Portfolio < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_types, dependent: :destroy
  scope :ptype, -> (p_type) { includes(:project_types).where(project_types: {ptype: p_type}) }
end
```

And you can call

```
Portfolio.ptype('web')
```